# App Loses Focus if Chrome Show Notifications Dialog Is Closed With X

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I have a button that allows users to turn on notifications
(no annoying pop-up at an unexpected time)

```
<span *ngIf="!showButton">
<div class="notificationsMsg">{{notificationMessage}}</div>
</span>
<span *ngIf="showButton">
<button mat-stroked-button
      id="sendButton"
      (click)="enableNotifications()">Enable Notifications</button>
</span>
```

When the button is clicked
I display the Chrome Allow Notifications dialog
And respond to the user's action
Then hide the button (you cannot show the dialog twice) and show a message

[image]

If the user selects BLOCK or ALLOW
Everything works as expected
Button Hidden, Message shown

If the user closes the dialog with the X
My code fires, but the page is not updated until you manually click on it

**Is there something I could do to in my code give the page focus again to hide the button and show the message?**

```
// the button was clicked
enableNotifications() {

Notification.requestPermission(perm => {
  if (perm === 'granted') {
    console.log('allow clicked');
    this.notificationMessage = 'Woo Hoo';
  } else  if (['default', 'denied'].indexOf(perm) > -1) {
    console.log('block clicked or dialog closed');
    this.notificationMessage = 'DENIED';
  }
  this.showButton = false;
});
}
```

Chrome Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can you explain better `My code fires, but the page is not updated until you manually click on it`? Which code? And what should be updated?

Comment: The variable used to show/hide the message and button is set, but they are not shown & hidden until I click on the page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your component variables within [Angular zone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone).

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  notificationMessage = '';
  showButton: boolean;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    Notification.requestPermission(perm => {
      if (perm === 'granted') {
        console.log('allow clicked');
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.showButton = false;
          this.notificationMessage = 'Woo Hoo';
        });

      } else if (['default', 'denied'].indexOf(perm) > -1) {
        console.log('block clicked or dialog closed');
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.showButton = false;
          this.notificationMessage = 'Denied';
        });
      }

    });
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwyebsw)

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I have never known about Angular zone. So much to learn.